# How to annotate text along curved lines in python and rotate the lines?

Tags: python

[image]

I have this image and I have to annotate texts along every curved line (like 'OI 8446', CaII 8498, etc.) at particular positions along y-axis. Each annotated text must coincide with the particular curved line where I want to place the annotated text. I am not understanding how to do this. Someone please help.

Comment: Click the option 'enter image description here' above to view the plot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Gourav. Please take the [tour] and read about [ask].

Comment: What do you call curve line? You should look at the annotate function: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html